# Lagging timers due to PanGesture?

Tags: ios

When timers are running and I am trying to drag a button around the screen, my timers lag. This is noticeable because the timers are moving images.

Is there a way to solve this by changing something, or do I have to change my whole project?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest either using CoreAnimation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/introduction/introduction.html) or for simple animations, UIView's `animateWithDuration:animations` method (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:).

The reason for this is that the Apple frameworks attempt to keep the animation timing correct and smooth, regardless of external events. In other words, if an external event causes the animation to drop some frames, the framework still produces a relatively nice looking animation by properly interpolating the animation over the specified duration.

If you want to stick with timers, do the interpolation yourself:

1. Remember the time at the beginning of your animation
2. Fire the timer at a regular interval
3. Based the difference between the new time and the original time, calculate where your image should be taking into account the total duration of the animation and the distance it needs to travel

This will produce a smoother result than a simple "move the image X pixels every Y milliseconds" approach and it will ensure the animation runs in exactly the specified duration.

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimer` is implemented as an event on the run loop. It doesn't make any promises about when it will fire, and is not appropriate for anything that is time critical. If you have an `NSTimer` firing more than once a second, you're probably using it for the wrong things. If you do things that cause the run loop to not process quickly, you will definitely have timer problems.

Pan gesture recognizers can send a lot of messages to the main run loop. This is usually fine, but especially if you do non-trivial work in the move callback, you could certainly disrupt your timers.

The right solution is generally to use UIView animations, Core Animation, or UIKit Dynamics to move things around the screen. That's what those tools are built for. @ksimons provides some good links. For non-animation actions that fire rapidly, GCD timers are usually a better solution than `NSTimer`.

If you need timers to do updates to the screen, you should always use `CADisplayLink` rather than an `NSTimer`. A common mistake people make is to schedule an `NSTimer` that updates faster than the screen does. `CADisplayLink` is best suited to custom drawing situations, not animations. Again, there are very good animation frameworks available.